# Creating conditional fields: How should I implement hook_form_alter()?

Tags: forms

*Backstory: I used and highly enjoyed [Conditional Fields modules](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) for D6 in the past. Currently using 7.x-3.x-dev. But had some issues recently with it and would rather just learn how to do it manually. Familiar with [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel), but had no luck successfully getting a complex `hook_form_alter()` to work. Always end up hitting a dead-end.*

What are the fundamentals of implementing a `hook_form_alter()`?

I'd like to get this process laid out and in one single location. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Conditional Fields module's features can be done with using [#states](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#states) attribute from form api in D7.

If you want to implement it, of course you need to use `hook_form_alter()` to bring additionaly attributes on existing fields. There many tutorials about the usage of `hook_form_alter()`.

Example of using of #states attribute:

```
  $form['student_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => array(
      'high_school'   => t('High School'),
      'undergraduate' => t('Undergraduate'),
      'graduate'      => t('Graduate'),
    ),
    '#title' => t('What type of student are you?')
  );
  $form['high_school'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('High School Information'),
    // This #states rule says that the "high school" fieldset should only
    // be shown if the "student_type" form element is set to "High School".
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="student_type"]' => array('value' => 'high_school'),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Example from [Examples for Developers module - form_example module](https://drupal.org/project/examples)

Comment: Ahh, been trying to use the #disabled attribute all along. Thanks for the help. A wild guess, can you have more than one field in this array validate in order to display the hidden field? (since the #states attribute pulls from an array)

Comment: Have a look on the Examples for Developers module - form_example module, there is good examples about #states with nested childs

Comment: @pico34, how can I do the same in Drupal 6?

Comment: @ARUN, this is not implemented in D6 form API. You have to do with your own custom jquery. Or with Conditional Fields module